# Keycloak Direct Access Grant not valid at keycloak userinfo endpoint

Tags: jwt, keycloak

I am trying to write tests for an API that uses Keycloak for authorization.

I can programmatically login to keycloak from the test script using `grant_type` password, and keycloak responds with a token.

When the API tries to verify that token using the Keycloak userinfo endpoint, I get a `403 Token Authorization Error`.

The same API validation function works fine for the same user, if I login to Keycloak manually through the web client. I have checked the API middleware and it receives the same token as was generated by keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

I found soluation in Keycloak official site.

The key point is create a scope name openid and append to the client with default setting.
After that everything work correct.

detail

https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/issue-on-userinfo-endpoint-at-keycloak-20/18461

--- old messge ---
I have a same trouble too.
If you just want to verify token, You can use this endpoint.
Be sure "Client authentication" is enabled, then you should use client_secret and client_id get the token

introspection_endpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/smart-outbound-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"

Answer (score 1):

If someone is getting:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Client not allowed for direct access grants"
}
```

when trying to get the token, you need to enable direct access grant for your client:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WOD.png]

Answer (score -1):

I guess your realm client does not have user management permission. Follow these steps and try again.

1. Using keycloak web client login as admin
2. Select realm > clients > select client
3. Set `Service Accounts Enabled` ON in client settings and save.
4. Then you will see new tab `Service Account Roles` select that.
5. Select `realm-management` from `Client Roles` dropdown.
6. Add `manage-users` permission
   [image]

Comment: tried this out but didnt work a bit